# Use values from previous row to aggregate values when row missing

Tags: java, iterator

I have a whole bunch of rows that contain tax payments.

Each row contains `PaymentDueDate`.

If row is missing in between `PaymentDueDate`s, I have to use same values from previous row to aggregate for all totals.

In below example, between `Row="2"` and `Row="3"`, data is missing for months 2015/09, 2015/10, 2015/11, 2015/12, 2016/01, 2016/02.

So, I have to use `Row="2"` values to use to account for missing rows.

```
<PaymentChangeMaintenance>
  <PaymentChangeMaintenanceTransaction Row="1">
         <BuydownSubsidyAmount>0.00</BuydownSubsidyAmount>
         <AnnualInterestRate>4.75000</AnnualInterestRate>
         <PIAmount>689.79</PIAmount>
         <PaymentDueDate>2015-07-01</PaymentDueDate>
         <CityTaxAmount>23.22</CityTaxAmount>
         <CountyTaxAmount>32.25</CountyTaxAmount>
  </PaymentChangeMaintenanceTransaction>
  <PaymentChangeMaintenanceTransaction Row="2">
         <BuydownSubsidyAmount>0.00</BuydownSubsidyAmount>
         <AnnualInterestRate>4.75000</AnnualInterestRate>
         <PIAmount>689.79</PIAmount>
         <PaymentDueDate>2015-08-01</PaymentDueDate>
         <CityTaxAmount>125.25</CityTaxAmount>
         <CountyTaxAmount>666.22</CountyTaxAmount>
  </PaymentChangeMaintenanceTransaction>
  <PaymentChangeMaintenanceTransaction Row="3">
         <BuydownSubsidyAmount>0.00</BuydownSubsidyAmount>
         <AnnualInterestRate>4.75000</AnnualInterestRate>
         <PIAmount>689.79</PIAmount>
         <PaymentDueDate>2016-03-01</PaymentDueDate>
         <CityTaxAmount>125.25</CityTaxAmount>
         <CountyTaxAmount>666.22</CountyTaxAmount>
  </PaymentChangeMaintenanceTransaction>
</PaymentChangeMaintenance>
```

Here is code someone wrote, but it is not clean-looking. I would like to use for-each :/

```
private void aggregateEscrowPaymountAmounts(List<PaymentChangeMaintenanceFieldsV214Type> fieldsType,
             PaymentChangeMaintenance paymentChangeMaintenance, final int numberOfTrialPayments) {
     AtomicInteger cnt = new AtomicInteger(1);
     Iterator<PaymentChangeMaintenanceFieldsV214Type> fieldsTypeIterator = fieldsType.iterator();
     PaymentChangeMaintenanceFieldsV214Type fieldType = fieldsTypeIterator.next();
     PaymentChangeMaintenanceFieldsV214Type nextFieldType = null;
     if (fieldsTypeIterator.hasNext()) {
                nextFieldType = fieldsTypeIterator.next();
     }
     LocalDate monthDate = fieldType.getNextPaymentDueDate();

     while (cnt.getAndIncrement() <= numberOfTrialPayments) {
                PaymentChangeMaintenance tempPaymentChangeMaintenance = createPaymentChangeMaintenanceEscrow(fieldType);
                paymentChangeMaintenance.aggregate(tempPaymentChangeMaintenance);
                monthDate = monthDate.plusMonths(1);
                if (nextFieldType != null) {
                       LocalDate nextFieldTypeDate = nextFieldType.getNextPaymentDueDate();

                       if (nextFieldTypeDate.getMonthValue() == monthDate.getMonthValue()) {
                               fieldType = nextFieldType;
                               if (fieldsTypeIterator.hasNext()) {
                                      nextFieldType = fieldsTypeIterator.next();
                               } else {
                                      nextFieldType = null;
                               }
                       }
                }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For this certain case you can use a following approach: determine a step - for you it's a month. Then initialize a default value for a case of absence of the value on the next step. Then use some method that will take a next value and default value and depends on a step presence will return one of them
Here is a pseudocode:

```
List<Item> items;
Item nextItem = items.get(0);
Value step = month;
for (int i = 1; i < items.size(); i++) {
  nextItem = getNextItem(items.get(i), nextItem, step);
  ****
}


Item getNextItem(Item nextItem, Item defaultItem, Value step) {
    if (!nextItem.getStepValue().equals(calcNext(step))) {
        return defaultItem;
    } else {
        return nextItem;
    }
}

StepValue calcNext(Value step) {
    /*some calculations. In your case month increment*/
}
```